# How to force unbold from execCommand edited text

Tags: javascript

I am using document.execCommand to bold and underline text, but I want to make a button that forces the text to be unbolded and not underlined, rather than simply toggling. I can’t use execCommand(“removeFormat”) either, as it is causing issues in my program. Is there a work around I can use to unbold/un-underline the text?

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  if (event.altKey){
    if (event.code === 'Digit1') {
// Unbold, unhighlight, un-underline // 
      document.execCommand("hiliteColor", false, "transparent")      
      changeFont('7.5pt') /* This goes into a function to change the fontsize */
  }
```

Comment: `myEditableDiv.innerHTML = myEditableDiv.innerText`

Comment: If you have other HTML which you want to stay untouched in that div (such as paragraphs): `myEditableDiv.querySelectorAll('b, strong, u').forEach(t => t.outerHTML = t.innerHTML)`

Comment: Sorry! I must have not included enough details. My problem is that I only want to unbold the selected text. So if I have an entire sentence that is bold, and I want to unbold two words in that sentence, the rest of the sentence stays bold.

Comment: Show your current code, so that no more bad assumptions are made

Comment: I updated it, thank you so much for your help. I have the unhighlight thing figured out, but I am not sure how to unbold or un-underline without using removeFormat, which causes some issues because it needs to be ran multiple times if the text is bolded, underlined, and highlighted

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove *all* formatting, you can easily do it by replacing the HTML with its text equivalent:

```js
const editor = document.getElementById("editor");
document.getElementById("unformat").addEventListener("click", () => {
  editor.innerHTML = editor.innerText;
});
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable>Mess <u>with me</u>, and <b>add crazy</b> formatting <b>to your heart&apos;s <u>content</u></b> then click <code>UNFORMAT</code></div>
<button id="unformat">UNFORMAT</button>
```

<s>If you want to *only* remove bolded text, you could replace the bold nodes with text, like this:</s> If you want to individually unformat something, you could do it like this (example with bolding):

```js
const editor = document.getElementById("editor");
document.getElementById("unbold").addEventListener("click", () => {
  // get all bolded elements
  Array.from(editor.getElementsByTagName("b")).forEach(i => {
    i.outerHTML = i.innerHTML; // replace the bold with its contents
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable>Mess <u>with me</u>, try <b>bolding</b> random <b>parts <u>then</u></b> click <code>UNBOLD</code></div>
<button id="unbold">UNBOLD</button>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your help. I think the issue arrises because a user can make a sentence bold like this <b.> hello my name is </b> but then want to make "my name" unbold. However, if the code were to try to unbold, it would unbold the entire sentence instead of the two words the user wants to be unbolded. Is this able to be done?

Comment: Oh, you want to unbold/unformat a _range_ of text that the user highlights? You might want to clarify that in the question...

Comment: I’m sorry. Totally my fault. Couldn’t find the right terminology. But yes, that’s what I’m trying to do. Thank you for your patience.